# I find that under iOS 7 a pickerview has vanished

Tags: ios7

When I swipe over the location it does call pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent. I can set a breakpoint and see the new value, but the control is not visible. The app has worked for four years.

Comment: Perhaps...its behavior changed?  You know, intentionally?

Comment: I see that the picker is there,but under iOS7 it has "evaporated". The slot machine structure is gone, leaving just the text elements and a couple of lines. That is fine, but how do make it work in 7 and 6?

Comment: You mean you see the values but not the wheel? [That's just how it looks now](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/06/14/ios-6-vs-ios-7-the-different-ui-views/).

Answer (score 1):

That's just the new iOS 7 looks, it has got a flat design and you have to follow those lines:

iOS 6                                                                     iOS 7
[image: Picker]
                              iOS 6                                                                     iOS 7